# Option for OTA Update In React Native without expo. are using code push fully free for ota update?

Tags: react-native, code-push, in-app-update, react-native-code-push

Hi Guys I want to implement OTA update in react native. I found an option using Codepush app center, but is it fully free for OTA update? because I saw pricing page. Is there any better option? thanks

A free OTA update service and can be implemented in react native would be great

Answer (score 0):

It is free, if your app build time is less than an amount of minutes, I would recommend using expo-updates. I've been using it for the bast 3 years, no issues, and totally free

Comment: Are there any option rather than using expo? Im using react native cli

Comment: you can still add expo-updates package

Answer (score 0):

code push is free , As per their official site

While CodePush is in beta, it will remain completely free to use, with absolutely no limits (e.g. # of apps, size of release assets). Additionally, even after the service “RTMs”, there will always be a free tier. Whether there will be any further changes, however, is currently TBD. We’re excited to see how developers make use of the service, and we look forward to getting lots of feedback from developers before making any changes to the pricing model.

Link. : https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/faq/index.html